# Tensorflow tf.random.normal() causes RAM usage to keep growing

Tags: tensorflow, memory-leaks, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras

**Issue:** Running TF 2.13.0, Python 3.8.3, I'm getting what looks like a memory leak from running the following simple code, in eager mode.

**Context:** I'm running RL algorithms using a TF-addon [NoisyDense](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/NoisyDense) layer, which exposes a function that does the below random sampling. Since it's being executed millions of times, it causes exploding RAM.

**Notes:**

- Wrapping the random sampling inside a function decorated with tf.function seems to avoid the issue.
- From spending some time looking into the issue, I have a vague understanding that this is caused by TF graph adding a new tensor every time the sampling is called in eager mode, w/o freeing the previous ones

**Question:** why is this exactly happening? Is this sampling function not meant to be used in this way, or does it always need to be used inside a tf.function? As I'm not a TF expert (especially graph vs eager mode) I'm hoping somebody can explain to me what I'm not or mis- understanding here. Googling the issue for hours has not left me much wise.

```
import os, psutil
process = psutil.Process()
print(process.memory_info().rss / 1000000)  # Ram usage

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

for _ in range(10):
    print(process.memory_info().rss / 1000000)
    for _ in range(5000):
        x = tf.random.normal(shape=(10000, 1))  # Causing growing RAM
```

Output:

```
382.963712
2.13.0
382.963712
385.220608
387.21536
388.927488
390.926336
392.392704
394.338304
396.374016
398.323712
400.273408
```

Comment: Can confirm with TF 2.13.0, python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04. This does not happen with TF 2.12.1, maybe you should write an issue on the TensorFlow github page.